# Image blur not working using Vague JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, blur

I am trying to blur the image like [**Here**](http://gianlucaguarini.github.io/Vague.js/) using **[Vague.js](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/Vague.js/blob/master/Vague.js)**

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<img id="yourelement" src="http://sea-captains-house.com/images/box-discover-oia/sunset.jpg" />
```

**jQuery**

```
var vague = $('#yourelement').Vague({
    intensity:      3,      // Blur Intensity
    forceSVGUrl:    false,   // Force absolute path to the SVG filter,
    // default animation options
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear' // here you can use also custom jQuery easing functions
    }
});

vague.blur();
```

Here is my **[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/9myhdyhe/3/)**

Please help me where I do mistake??

Comment: Check your console errors: `Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/vague.js/blob/master/Vague.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` It's not loading the Vague.js script properly.

Comment: So what I have to do to import external js? Can you please edit my fiddle?

Comment: Read [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24548325/2539335).

Comment: @DarkAshelin Thanks a lots for your point. Rawgit solved my problem.

Comment: It's ok..np All d Best for your search. :)