# How to refresh datatables with new data in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, datatables

I am using datatables `1.10.19` in vue js. Here i have dynamic table on clicking some button it filters and replace table by new data to tr tag of table.How can i refresh table with new content? i used `clear`, `destroy` but no thing works.Here is my entire code.

[Code Link](https://pastebin.com/LS9tkX3q)

Comment: could you please share more of your code where we can see, how you get the new data and so on..

Comment: try `$('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();`

Comment: i am using datatables with vue js. For the first time datatable works but on calling dynamic data using filter and reinatilize it, it wont work.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Share your entire code fore better understanding

Comment: I have updated my question with pastebin link. Please go through it.

Comment: if you have done it right way, the content should get replace with new one. I cant just tell you whats the issue but what I think is in many cases I have seen is how you set your reactive properties and are they really reactive after initialization. plz check [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) official docs for reactivity if you think that might be the case here.

Comment: The problem may be caused by the DOM data not being updated before you update the dataTable. So you have to wait for next Tick by using [this.$nextTick()](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) . [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755853/implementing-vue-js-datatables-properly) that might help you

Comment: @salinkunwar: regarding your bounty, if you are unhappy with the "_current answers_", you should comment them saying in what respect they lack some details, so that their authors have a chance to improve them. You could also consider removing the _accepted_ flag (if you can).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your code like this, it should work

```
$('.reportDataTableModelWise').DataTable().destroy();
```

before calling data from `this.$store.commit('modelWiseTabularReport');`

and update your updated code like this

```
this.$nextTick(function() {
        $('.reportDataTableModelWise').DataTable({
            'destroy'     : true,
            'paging'      : true,
            'lengthChange': true,
            'searching'   : true,
            'ordering'    : true,
            'order'       : [[ 5, 'desc' ]],
            'info'        : true,
            'autoWidth'   : false,
            'dom'         : 'Blfrtip',
            'buttons'     : [
                {
                    'extend': 'csv',
                    'title': this.$route.meta.report_name + ' Report'
                },
                {
                    'extend': 'pdf',
                    'title': this.$route.meta.report_name + ' Report'
                },
                {
                    'extend': 'print',
                    'title': this.$route.meta.report_name + ' Report'
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

The `$nextTick` is necessary to ensure Vue has flushed the new data to the DOM, before re-initializing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also redraw yout table by using :

```
   ...
   watch: {
     myData () { // data used in the table
       this.$nextTick (() => { // wait until data fully updated before re-render new DOM 
         $('.reportDataTableModelWise').DataTable().draw();
       })
     }
   }
```