# how to display json or fetch data to datatables vue

Tags: vue.js, datatables, axios, vuex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Bn3.png)

and this my code

```
export default {
  name: "pegawai",
  data() {
      return {
      }
  },
  created(){
     this.$store.dispatch("GetPegawai");
     this.tabel();
  },
  computed: {
    fetch(){
      return this.$store.state.pegawai 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    tabel() {
        this.$nextTick(()=>{
            $('.example').DataTable();
        })
    }
}
```

why this happens, how to load json into datatables ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing Vue.js + DataTables properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755853/implementing-vue-js-datatables-properly)

Comment: how to implement with vuex ?

Comment: Here is a working example at codepen: https://codepen.io/akfred/pen/xaeYEW
Maybe that helps you.