# How to use path.js as an external resource without require (jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, external, require, jsfiddle

I wanted to test out path.js in jsfiddle, so I decided to make a 2-3 line [jsfiddle script](https://jsfiddle.net/_Auro/wy351n87/11/). I included path.min.js as an external resource, but when I try running it, I see errors that the join function is not defined.

This was the error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: join is not defined
```

Outside of jsfiddle, normally I would:

```
var path = require('path');
path.join("a","b");
```

So I am thinking `join("a","b","c");` is not the right usage for this kind of 'import', or maybe just for the path.min.js library in specific.

I've tried both [path.js and path.min.js from cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/path.js) (the latter is what jsfiddle selects when using the search bar in its resources tab), and  had the same error with both.

Comment: What you linked is some random routing library, it has nothing to do with Node `path` module, if that's what you want.

Comment: @DallogFheir Yes, I am trying to use the Node `path` module, should have read the description on cdnjs. Would the only option be to do one of the options in [this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841026/reference-github-file-in-jsfiddle/29121908#29121908) (I would just use [npm's link](https://github.com/jinder/path) to the `path` source on git.)